# HeightAnchor constraint does not work. UIImageView does notstretch to the size according to the aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiimage, constraints

I try to get UIImage aspect ratio the same as in source image:

```
            let im = UIImage(named: curQuestion!.images[0]+".jpg")
            let h = im!.size.height
            let w = im!.size.width

            cardImage1TopConst.constant = 15
            image1.image = im
            image1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image1.widthAnchor, multiplier: h/w).isActive = true

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This function is called several times (source image changes). Almost always everything is ok, but sometimes image does notstretch to the size according to the aspect ratio. (If I quit this view controller and get back, it can be fixed)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can be a problem with thread. you must call this function on Main Thread. otherwise, it will not work as you expected.

Comment: If you are calling this more than once, you are setting multiple height anchors. I assume you are getting auto-layout warning / error messages in debug console when you do that. Is there a reason you don't simply set `Content Mode` to `Aspect Fit` on your image view?